# Delete string without background color from richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox with some text in that I got from a webpage.I need to delete all the text without background color but also i would like to keep the market words in same row as it was before deleting lines. Here is the example of the text:

[Print screen](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/98428801.png/)

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way is to go in reverse and examine each character one by one.

```
For i As Integer = RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1 To 0 Step -1
  RichTextBox1.Select(i, 1)
  If Not (RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Chr(10) Or _
          RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Chr(13)) Then
    If RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor.R = 255 AndAlso _
       RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor.G = 255 AndAlso _
       RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor.B = 255 Then
      RichTextBox1.SelectedText = String.Empty
    End If
  End If
Next
```

This can be quite flicky, in which case, try creating a new RichTextBox control in code, transfer the contents, and do the work there.  Then transfer the results back to your existing RichTextBox control.

Comment: Great working perfectly :) know what i need is to check if the line has more then x characters if not delete complete line. Thank youu veryy muchh